# Wordpress plugin work

Tags: wordpress, plugins, content-management-system

Go to the following link and give me idea how to do this thing in word-press.Here is link http://www.coursesearch.unimelb.edu.au/#/?PathId=16&List=interests

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you could describe "this thing".

Comment: thanks Matt Gibson.As there are four column in the link i have provided.Same thing I made my mind to make in my word-press project.Selecting one relates to other and so on.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

all boxes are written in the html, they are then hidden with display: none and set dislay: vsible with anchor tags. e.g. a link item sets display:visible whatever other box you decide. This is jquery by the way, not a plugin, no a wordpress, not a cms issue.